# Approximating PL homeomorphism by diffeomorphisms in Euclidean space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, differential-topology

The question is whether a piecewise function can be approximated by diffeomorphic functions in the following two situations.

I'm not really familiar with these piecewise stuffs. So it may be stupid questions.

1. Lef $f:[0,1]^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be piecewise linear embedding. Then, is there diffeomorphic embedding $g:[0,1]^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that approximates $f$ in the uniform sense?
2. Is piecewise linear homeomorphism $F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ can be approximated by diffeomorphism in the uniform sense?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For question 2, see remark 10 [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/problems.pdf). The PL case is even easier and the answer is positive in all dimensions, including 4.  One caveat: The topology in the space of homeomorphisms used there is not uniform but uniform on compacts. I do not think it makes a difference though.

Comment: @Misha Thank you for the comment! I found the mention that the PL  homeomorphism can be approximated by diffeomorphism in the proof of Theorem 4 in [Connell](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1970346.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Aaf894cc989421c2e5dab79a678ff2a84&ab_segments=&origin=&acceptTC=1) originally from Theorem 6.2 in [Munkres](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1970228.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Ab80d0689e4ff4ee0a4ae60f1cb99a876&ab_segments=&origin=)